# Echarts.js: Detect a click on a subset of data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I want to detect a click on a particular subset in a bar chart. As I want to init a new chart after the click, with the data from the clicked subset. Currently when I click on chart bars, I get data of the whole chart and can't retrieve data of just one bar.

Here is what I have:

```
<template>
 <chart :options="chartOptionsBar"
           :autoresize="true"
           ref="barChart"
           @click="mergeOptions(chartOptionsBar)"></chart>
<template>

<script>
...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      manualOptions: '',
      chartOptionsBar: {
        xAxis: {
          data: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'value',
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
              { value: 335, name: '1' },
              { value: 310, name: '2' },
              { value: 234, name: '3' },
              { value: 135, name: '4' },
            ],
          },
        ],
        title: {
          text: 'Quarterly Sales Results',
          x: 'center',
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 24,
          },
        },
        color: ['#127ac2'],
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    mergeOptions (options) {
      console.log(options.series[0]);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to detect the clicked subset by adding a refs attribute and the click event to the component and passing a function. Then I put this function in methods:

```
methods: {
    getDataSubset() {
      this.$refs.barChart.chart.on('click', (params) => {
        this.subset = params.data;
      });
    },
  },
```

Comment: What this does is it attaches an event listener to the chart, after which clicking the chart produces the wanted result. In other words, the chart now requires a double click instead of just a single one to function as a button. This might not be what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

In your click handler you are passing in a reference to the original config object for the chart, so this is what will be available to you in your mergeOptions function

If you remove the parenthesis and argument your function will get the event information for the click event `@click="mergeOptions"`

```
mergeOptions (eventInfo) {
  console.log(eventInfo);
  // hopefully this information will be a bit more use
}
```

According to the documentation [echarts.baidu.com/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20actions%20in%20ECharts%0D](https://echarts.baidu.com/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20actions%20in%20ECharts%0D) this information object will allow you to determine which bar was clicked.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to initialise a new chart after the click? I suppose it will happen inside the same function.

Comment: For a quick guide to adding components programmatically https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/